# XRDP shows "black" mouse cursor

Tags: xrdp

I've currently installed xrdp 0.61 on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS system.
I can remotely login using the sessman-XVNC config and get my 
xfce4 desktop, but the mouse cursor is not drawn correctly.

It has the correct shape but is drawn completely black.

Can anybody help me to fix this?